# curdate() causes error in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

i am using navicat8 for MySQL for writing trigger, bellow is my trigger statement.

```
insert into two(name,curdate()) 
select name from one
```

but it will display error while saving trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the **name of the column** instead of passing `CURDATE()`.

Use the following syntax,

```
insert into two (name, colName) 
select name, CURDATE() 
from one
```

**UPDATE 1**

So here's what you are going to do.

- You need to add `UNIQUE` constraint on column `Name` on table `two`.

To alter the table,

```
ALTER TABLE tableNamehere ADD CONSTRAINT two_uq UNIQUE(name);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dc4c/1)

Comment: insert into two(name, date) 
select name, curdate()
from one on duplicate key update name=values(name)

Comment: @ishwar what's your question? `:D`

Comment: i wrote this above and its will insert only if there is not same entry in table "two" but i need to check that date field same then i need to update..

Comment: i seen but i need to check date field contains duplicate or not.

Comment: because i am implementing this concept in Myweb site for storing the daily stock details

Comment: so need to check first if its todays date data allready exist then i need to update.else i need to insert

Comment: i need to give where condition but its showing errors. the code is

insert into closingstockt(CLS_BSID,CLS_Qty,CLS_SQty,CLS_CDate)
select BS_ID as CLS_BSID,BS_Qty as CLS_Qty,BSS_Qty as CLS_SQty,curdate() from barstockt
 on duplicate key update  CLS_Qty=BS_Qty,CLS_SQty=BSS_Qty where CLS_BSID=BS_ID

Comment: the `WHERE` clause should come before `...on duplicate key update...`

Comment: if i wrote this way then its check in barstockt table and i need to give where clause in closingstockt



insert into closingstockt(CLS_BSID,CLS_Qty,CLS_SQty,CLS_CDate)
select BS_ID as CLS_BSID,BS_Qty as CLS_Qty,BSS_Qty as CLS_SQty,curdate() from barstockt
where CLS_BSID=BS_ID on duplicate key update  CLS_Qty=BS_Qty,CLS_SQty=BSS_Qty

Comment: you need to do it on separate query.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into two(name, date_col) 
select name, curdate()
from one
```

First you have to name the columns you want to insert into, and then the values. If you want to fill all columns from your table you can leave the column name part and do

```
insert into two 
select name, curdate()
from one
```

Comment: sir, i having one question ..i need to insert data on table name "two" from "one" only if todays's date  is not exist else if todays date exist then i need to update data. so how i implement ?

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Comment: i seen that post.but i need to check the date column.

Comment: insert into two(name, date) 
select name, curdate()
from one on duplicate key update name=values(name)

Comment: how to check date column only.if its exist then i need to update else i need to insert

Comment: insert into closingstockt(CLS_BSID,CLS_Qty,CLS_SQty,CLS_CDate)
select BS_ID as CLS_BSID,BS_Qty as CLS_Qty,BSS_Qty as CLS_SQty,curdate() from barstockt
 on duplicate key update  CLS_Qty=BS_Qty,CLS_SQty=BSS_Qty where CLS_BSID=BS_ID

this statement cause error because of where condition, plz help me where i need to write where condition? 
actually i need to check where condition while updating row

Comment: Write another question about it.